# Which is a better XML attribute: base=64 or encoding=base64

Tags: xml, encoding

I am designing an XML and wish to allow binary data to be encoded as either base16 or base64.  The default will be base16.

For specifying base64, I wish to have an attribute. My two options are:

```
<foo encoding='base64'>TqpuiunH0mEWcSkYSINkTQffuny=</foo>
```

and:

```
<foo base='64'>TqpuiunH0mEWcSkYSINkTQffuny=</foo>
```

I think that the first is more descriptive but suspect that the second might be better. I'm looking for people's reactions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as `base64` is an encoding, the more semantic markup would be `encoding="base64"`.

People seeing `base` may think about a decimal base or binary, for example, which I don't believe is what you would want a reader to think.

Comment: Thanks. That's my feeling as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what the other options are. If the other options are base="2", base="10", or base="32" then I would use base="64". If the other options are encoding="hexBinary" and encoding="ebcdic" then I would use encoding="base64". I don't think you can decide the best representation for an attribute when you only know one of its possible values.

Comment: Thanks. I think that you've convinced me to go with encoding="base64"